# How to install OS X on an external drive connected to your Mac from Linux

Tags: linux, macos

Currently I have [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) Linux running on my MacBook Pro. I want to try out OS X again, but keeping Linux for now. Can I install OS X to a USB drive without touching my internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

Your external drive needs a GUID partition with at least 8 GB of available space to install OS X. For best results, the volume should be formatted as Mac OS X Extended format (not FAT, NTFS, or EXFAT).
Attach a USB, FireWire, or Thunderbolt storage device to your computer, or insert an SDHC or SDXC card into the SD card slot if your Mac has one:

1. Set up a `gpt` partition table
2. Restart up your Mac. Immediately after you hear the startup sound, press and hold the `Command+R` on your keyboard.
3. After you see an Apple logo or globe appear, you can release the keys. If you're prompted to select a Wi-Fi network, select a network that has a working Internet connection.
4. When the Recovery screen appears, make sure you're connected to the Internet. If not, select a Wi-Fi network with a working Internet connection from the Wi-Fi menu.
5. Select the option to Install OS X from the Recovery window.
6. Follow the onscreen instructions to complete the installation. When you're asked to select a drive for installation, click the button "Show All Drives". Be sure you select the external storage device you've connected for this purpose, not your computer's built-in startup drive.

References:

- [apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202796)